# Facebook doesn't redirect to redirecturi after login stays in the same facebook login page

Tags: php, facebook

I am following the code from:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

```
require_once 'config.php';
error_reporting(-1);
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
    require_once('includes/Facebook/autoload.php');

    $facebook= new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'                => $setting['facebook_appid'],
        'app_secret'            => $setting['facebook_secret'],
        'default_graph_version' =>'v2.5',

    ]);
    $helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $redirect_uri = 'http://mysuite.com/facebook_auth.php';
    $permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_uri,$permissions);
    echo "<html><body><script>window.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script></body></html>";
```

It works but it doesn't redirect to my redirect page after login. it is not coming to facebook_auth.php.

After facebook login it stays in the same facebook login page.

Comment: And the script the code you have shown us is in, is named how?

Comment: @CBroe facebookloginredirect.php bro

Comment: And does the login URL that gets created contain the right value for the redirect_uri parameter as specified in your code, or is it something else?

Comment: @CBroe I have rectified the problem bro, it was in my code, i redirected to login page before trying the accesstoken...